# What does それ refer to in それでいい in this exchange?

Tags: meaning, spoken-language

「ええい、御託はいい！！それより流星。お前は見たくはないのか？嫁達の喜ぶ姿を。」

「嫁達の喜ぶ姿…」

「しかも温泉で！」

「お、温泉で…」

「…わ、分かった。嫁達の健康と笑顔には変えられん。」

「ふははははっ、それでいい、それでいいのだ、流星！」

In this exchange I'm a bit confused as to what the それ is actually referring to. In this conversation they were trying to convince him to go with him and the 嫁達 to a 温泉 and after much persistence(other stuff before this part of the exchange has been removed to keep it short) he eventually gives in and gives the excuse/reasoning 嫁達の健康と笑顔には変えられん. Now normally I'd think that それ would refer to the actual utterance itself but I can't see it literally referring to the previous utterance apart from the fact that it's basically 流星 agreeing to what the other person had suggested(i.e 温泉で嫁達の喜ぶ姿をみたい). Can anyone explain exactly to what それ refers to in this situation?

edit:
Does it refer to 流星's desire (温泉で嫁達の喜ぶ姿をみたい)
Does it refer to 流星's acceptance of his idea
Or what does it refer to?

Comment: Does it say 「変えられん」 and not 「代えられん」?

Comment: It does say 変えられん

Comment: Then it must be a typo or bad spelling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「それ」 here does ***not*** refer to an actual utterance made.  Instead, it would refer to 流星's logic, reasoning or way of thinking that has been expressed by the line 「…わ、分かった。嫁達{よめたち}の健康{けんこう}と笑顔{えがお}には代えられん。」= "Alright.  Nothing could replace our wives' good health and smiles.".

「それでいい」 often means 「その考{かんが}え方{かた}でいい」 or 「そのやり方でいい」　and this one is no exception.  It is an expression of approvement of another person's action or way of thinking.

It is kind of close to ***"Way to go!"*** in feeling.