# What does などそれでいい mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, particle-など

> Eマウントはシステムが....と言っている人の考えが、なんとなくわかってきた。アダプタでAマウントいけるとはいっても、コントラストAFが更に遅くなるというわけで、まあAF**などそれでいい**という考え方もあろうし、そうじゃない人もいるだろうし。まあ人それぞれか

Is it something like :  **"it's ok even if it's ..."** ?

I would be grateful if someone could help me :]

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33289/7810

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> camera.itmedia.co.jp/dc/articles/1009/14/news026.html (2010) - 快適な撮影に欠かせないオートフォーカス。デジタルカメラでは主に「コントラストAF」「位相差AF」の2つの方式が用いられています。

> 「それでいい」 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/27289
>    ......... It is kind of close to "Way to go!" in feeling.

Yes, when 天才バカボンのパパ [Tensai Bakabon no Papa] says それでいいのだ! , he means "It's all good." (Life is good)

Here, it's a bit different.

> アダプタでAマウントいけるとはいっても、コントラストAFが更に遅くなるというわけで、まあAFなどそれでいいという考え方もあろうし

Contrast AF (Auto Focus) is going to be even slower, and, well, some may tend to think that (slow AF) is fine / alright / ok  -- (that's tolerable).

Answer (score 2):

> まあAFなどそれでいいという考え方もあろうし

- など here is like [なんか/なんて](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=nado%3B%20nanka%3B%20nante), and is used to make light of AF.
- それ refers to what is said previously in the sentence: The slow AF due to the use of the adapter.
- ～でいい implies something is not the ideal option but is okay/acceptable. See [this](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=2423).

All in all, "AFなどそれでいい" means "AF is okay even with its slowness", implying "That's how AF is" or "You cannot expect much of AF in the first place".

Answer (score 1):

It makes better sense to translate everything starting with

"まあＡＦなど”

"Since it's only "AF," some consider it is not big deal and therefore, it is fine, while others may say otherwise. I guess it depends."